# BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 107: Method [getById] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Getting `Method [getById] does not exist` error when I submit a username.

Username Controller:

```
use Auth;
use MostWanted\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class UsernameController extends Controller
{
public function getUsername()
{
    return view('dashboard.getusername');       
}

public function postUsername(Request $request)
{   
    $id = Auth::id(); 

    $user = $this->getById($id);

    $this->validate($request, [
    'username' => 'required|unique:users|regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9.]+$/|max:50',
    ]);

    $user->username = $request->input('username');

    return view('home');

}
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

/** 
*Entering Username
*/

Route::get('/choose_username', [
'uses' => '\MostWanted\Http\Controllers\UsernameController@getUsername',
'as' => 'dashboard.getusername',
]);

Route::post('/choose_username', [
'uses' => '\MostWanted\Http\Controllers\UsernameController@postUsername',
]);

});
```

getusername.blade.php:

```
@extends('templates.default')

@section('title')
MostWanted | Enter your username
@endsection

@section('content')
<div style="min-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; top: 75px;">
<div class="row" style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; border: 2px solid #000; padding: 40px;">
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="width: 600px; color: #999; padding: 44.5px 0;">
    <h3 style="color: #000; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 10px;">Enter a username</h3>
        <form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('dashboard.getusername') }}">
        <div>
            <div>Your public username is the same as your Profile address:

                <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <div>mostwanted.com/<span id="display_name">
                    <script>
                    $('#username').keyup(function () {
                    $('#display_name').text($(this).val());
                    });
                    </script>
                    </span></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('username') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="username" class="control-label">Choose a username</label>
                    <input style="width: 456px;" placeholder="e.g.&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->getUsernameOrName() }}" type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username" value="">
                        @if ($errors->has('username'))
                            <span class="help-block" style="font-size: 12px; margin-bottom: 0;">{{ $errors->first('username') }}</span>
                        @endif
                </div>
                <div>Note:&nbsp;Your username cannot be changed and should include your authentic name&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                <button style="float: right;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save username</button>
            </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>  
</div>
@stop
```

Am I defining `$id` wrong or something? getusername.blade.php is a form to enter username for first time login users, the conditions work and I've entered a username into the database through MySQL Workbench but when I try entering a username like a user would, the error appears. I want to make sure that the username entered will be aligned with the logged in user's entered details. The last time I did it, the usernames entered were creating new remember tokens every time.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the rest of your controller code I can only assume you are trying to fetch an instance of the User model by `$id`.

If that is the case, then:

There is no method `getById()`, I think you mean `find($id)`, also its a static method that needs to be called like this:

```
User::find($id);
```

Comment: I am getting `BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2251:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::id()` after I changed `$id` to `$id = User::id();` and `$user = $this->find($id);`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`$user = $this->getById($id);`

With:

`$user = User::find($id);`

Explanation: Using `$this` in the context of the controller will lookup the method `getById` in the controller, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I am getting `BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2251: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::id()` after I changed `$id` to `$id = User::id();` and `$user = User::find($id);`

Comment: that error comes from this line: `$id = Auth::id();` which i don't know what you meant by it.

Comment: I am trying to fetch the id of the logged in user so they can add a unique username to their row in the database.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether getById($id) is written in UsernameController . 
If not, please write the function in the same controller.

That may be the error.

Comment: I am getting `BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2251:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::id()` after I changed `$id` to `$id = User::id();` and `$user = $this->find($id);` `getById($id)` is in the controller.